# URL parameters blown away by CFLOGIN?

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

I'm trying to use CFLOGIN with code only slightly modified from what is described on the [Adobe CFLOGIN documentation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c30.html) to demo an application.

The application sends an email to a user containing a link like:
[theURL]/loggedin/addplayertomatch.cfm?match_ID=[theID]

If the user is already logged in, clicking this link works great.  If they're not logged in, application.cfc includes the loginform.cfm appropriately, where the login form action points to:

```
<form action="#CGI.script_name#?#CGI.query_string#" method="Post">
```

(the query string still includes my match_ID parameter at this point).  When I submit the login form, though, the page URL ends up looking like:

```
[theURL]/loggedin/addplayertomatch.cfm?CFID=5833675&CFTOKEN=7f75c4fe49d10887-F39D4788-D376-1349-E971B9C4122031A0
```

The match_ID parameter has now been lost, replaced by CFID & CFTOKEN.  For demo purposes, I don't really mind the CFID & CFTOKEN joining in the fun, but where did my match_ID URL parameter go & how can I get it back?

Note: There aren't any CFLOCATIONs in my application.cfc or loginform.cfm.

Thanks!

Comment: On the login form, what are the url variables?

Comment: The match_ID=[theID] variable from my email link is the only thing in the form action's CGI.query_string.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: And, still on the login form, if you look at the debugging info, what is the value of cgi.query_string?

Comment: Within the login form, the cgi.script_name is /loggedin/addplayertomatch.cfm and the query_string is match_ID=25 (for example), which seems right so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `clientManagement` enabled on your application. You could try turning it off if it is not needed and see if the CFID etc. won't overwrite your own querystring.

Alternatively, you could try grabbing the querystring at the beginning of `OnRequestStart` with something like:

```
<cfset request.qString = listLast(request,"?")>
```

Then append it to the form action with something like this:

```
<form action="#CGI.script_name#?#CGI.query_string#&request.qString" method="Post">
```

For more info on clientManagment:

- [CFApplication Tag Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fd5.html)
- [Configuring and using client variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fd5.html)

Comment: FYI, tags like cfml/html/xml are not visible unless you apply code formatting. For inline use [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) or for code blocks, use the code button in the toolbar ie `{}` or indent four (4) spaces.

Comment: I think so, but thanks Dan for the edits to make it more clear and Leigh for the info on formatting.

Comment: Welcome J. Nilles! I'm always impressed with people whose first interaction with Stack Overflow is to _answer_ a question rather than _ask_ one.

Comment: I think the request scope and the request argument passed into OnRequestStart straight from Adobe's CFLOGIN page `<cfargument name = "request" required="true"/>` are partially clobbering each other.  `<cfset request.qString = "test">` in the OnRequestStart generates a "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members."

Comment: If I change the name of the request argument in OnRequestStart to `<cfargument name = "myrequest" required="true"/>` (to remove the conflict), and output myrequest, it contains only  `/loggedin/addplayertomatch.cfm`, so it looks like the query string URL parameters are already gone (and `<cfset request.qString = listLast(request,"?")>` can't find anything after the ?...

Comment: cgi.query_string still has the URL parameter in it, so `<cfset request.qryString = cgi.query_string> ` seems good.  But, then the `<form action="http://www.findmepaddle.com#CGI.script_name#?#CGI.query_string#&#Request.qryString#" method="Post">` seems to be ending up the URL parameters twice: `[theURL]/loggedin/addplayertomatch.cfm?match_ID=25&match_ID=25`!   Remove the `&#Request.qryString#` off the end, or append `&test=yes` and the old CFID/CFTOKEN no matchID returns after the quickest flicker of a Chrome message, I think? "redirect loop" (there from the beginning?).

Comment: My application doesn't client management.  Adding `<cfset This.clientmanagement="no">` to my application.cfc cfcomponent doesn't seem to have any effect on the CFID/CFTOKENs in the URL, though.  The documentation seems better for turning client management on & using than turning it off.  Am I missing an important bit?

Comment: If you are not interested in keeping the CFID etc., you might try removing the cgi.query_string, as in:
`<form action="http://www.findmepaddle.com#CGI.script_name#?#Request‌​.qryString#" method="Post">`

Comment: This is all well and good but the OP already has the correct information in his form tag.  The extra information gets prepended on form submission.

Comment: Confirming what Dan said.  `<form action="#CGI.script_name#?#request.qryString#" method="Post">` leads to the same result as with the cgi.query_string.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I didn't read your question carefully enough. Let me think about it. If I get some time later today, I'll try to recreate the issue.

Comment: I appreciate it, JN!

Comment: Chris, I haven't forgotten about this. But I have not been able to recreate the problem, either. Can you tell me more about what happens when it gets to addplayertomatch.cfm?

Comment: Doh!  I'm embarassed to say this, but after reading your last comment I realized that a CFLOCATION at the end of my addplayertomatch.cfm script set for a different use case was redirecting to itself and causing the URL parameter oddities I was seeing (and that flickered error in Chrome).  Apologies for not realizing this sooner, but thanks to JN & DB for helping me figure out the issue.

Comment: No worries, I've been there plenty of times thinking the problem is one place and it turns out to be somewhere else. Glad you got it resolved.